# How to replace a specific character in a substring using regex?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, replace, substring

#### My objective

**This question is about Visual Studio Code search box.**

I want to replace all the "spaces" by the character "_" inside the `my substring with spaces` of mystring

for example:

-> From

```
{
    "Show_details": mystring("my substring with spaces"),
    "Type_of_event": mystring("my substring with spaces2"),
}
```

-> To

```
{
    "Show_details": mystring("my_substring_with_spaces"),
    "Type_of_event": mystring("my_substring_with_spaces2"),
}
```

#### What I tried

I only managed to get the `my_substring_with_spaces`. But I do not understand how to proceed further.

```
Search: mystring\("([a-z]*?( )[a-z]*?)"\)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?<=mystring\("[^"]*)\s+(?=[^"]*"\))
```

**Details**

- `(?<=mystring\("[^"]*)` - immediately to the left, there must be `mystring("` and then 0 or more chars other than `"`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces (remove `+` if two consecutive spaces must be converted to two consecutive `_`s)
- `(?=[^"]*"\))` - immediately to the right, there must be 0 or more chars other than `"` and then `")`.

See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: regex killer 

Comment: In the `Edit->Find in Files` it shows the error `Regex parse error: Lookbehind assertion is not fixed length`. Any idea ?

Comment: @micaball Yes, do not use this regex in *Find in files*, it uses a different regex flavor.